# Removing a fixed character in the middle of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine the best/correct SQL Server function to remove a character in the middle of a string.

Values:

```
CAAxxB
CBBxx
CBAxxB
CBBxxB
  ^
```

I want to remove the character in the third position only (with no space) and leave the remaining characters (xx are always numbers)

Result:

```
CAxxB
CBxx
CBxxB
CBxxB
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
  SELECT STUFF(ColumnName, 3, 1, '')
```

[Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3445/1)

Comment: Nice answer! STUFF is certainly a solution. My answer shows an alternative of the concatenation of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(10) = 'CAAxxB'
SELECT 
    substring(@test, 1,2) + substring(@test, 4,50) -- Make sure this last value is large enough
   ,substring(@test, 1,2) + right(@test, len(@test)-3)
   ,stuff(@test, 3,1,'')
```

Comment: `substring(@test, 1,2)` is also `left(@test, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
select substring(val, 1, 2) + substring(val, 4, len(val))
from txt
```

Example data-source and structure:

```
create table txt(val varchar(32));

insert into txt(val) values
('123456'),
('789012'),
('345678'),
('901234'),
('123'),
('12'),
('567890');
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/415a9/1

Explanation: `substring` returns a chunk of a textual value starting from an index up until a certain length (indexing starts from 1). So, if we want to avoid the third character, then we concatenate two substring, the first containing the string up to the character to be omitted and the second starting from the next character up until the end.